# Java : cannot create a file, write access denied

Tags: file, ubuntu, jakarta-ee

I am installing my webapp(J2EE on tomcat7) on a Ubuntu server.

In my webapp, on my dev pc, I am creating a text file :

```
File file = new File("VE_EXPORT.TXT");          
FileWriter writer;  
writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
printer.write(necr+jnal+datp+dath+npie+cptg+libe+mont+codc+npoint+codeana+libCompte+"O"+newLine);
printer.close();            
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
response.reset();
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setContentLength((int) (file.length()));
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
IOUtils.copyLarge(fileInputStream, output);
file.delete();
output.flush();
```

It works fine.
But on the ubuntu server I have a 'permission denied'.
Is there a way not to have this error?
Do I need to do a new file if I just need to flush the output?
Or a way to configure the ubuntu server in order to allow  java (or tomcat7 or else) to create the file?

Thanks.

Comment: try run the app as the owner of the file, test with root first.

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

use chmod to get write access.

Comment: first of all try to give a path with your file name `File f = new File(this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
     + "/temp/" + name);`

Comment: It 's written in the folder webapps/myapp. I ve tried a chmod 777 on this folder but I m still getting this error. Is there a way to write "in memory" the file and then flush it?